# LLVM vs GNU assembler, how to replace .struct in LLVM

Tags: assembly, struct, clang, arm64, gnu-assembler

With the GNU assembler (arm64 target), I use `.struct` directives to define local layouts, for instance the stack frame of a function:

```
        .struct 0            // stack frame layout.
mul.call_frame: .space  16   // call frame (x29, x30)
mul.iter:       .space  8    // iteration count
...
                .align  4    // align stack frame on 16 bytes
mul.stack_size:
        .text
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -mul.stack_size]!
```

On macOS (M1), the LLVM assembler does not recognize the `.struct` directive

```
<instantiation>:3:9: error: unknown directive
        .struct 0
        ^
```

How would you replace `.struct 0` using the LLVM assembler?
The idea is to switch to a dummy absolute section (never allocated).

```
$ as --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: You can try `.set mul.call_frame, 0` to set to an absolute value.

Comment: @fuz, this is the old method I used before, defining all symbols from the previous one + size, etc. But this does not allow the convenient .space and .align directives to define the structure layout.